# C# : Using the ?: Operator for Functions?

Tags: c#

I wanted to asked a question about the ? conditional operator. The common syntax for the function is as follows (Found on the Microsoft site)

```
int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
string classify;

// if-else construction.
if (input < 0)
    classify = "negative";
else
    classify = "positive";

// ?: conditional operator.
classify = (input < 0) ? "negative" : "positive"; //<----
```

It is typically used when assigning a value to a variable but I had a thought about using it for running functions instead.

```
int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
string classify;

// if-else construction.
if (input < 0)
    RunScriptA();
else
    RunScriptB();

// ?: conditional operator.
(input < 0) ? RunScriptA()" : RunScriptB(); //<----
```

Having this sort of power would save many lines of code. Sadly I got syntax errors trying my go of the idea. So I wanted to know if what I wanted was feasible in C# and if so, how?

Also have an awesome Christmas everyone!

Comment: That should just work, granted you remove the excessive `"` and if both methods return the same type, which you assign to a variable. If you want help getting compiler errors fixed, include them in your question. Read [ask].

Comment: What's the return types of `RunScriptA` and `RunScriptB`? You can't do this if they're both void since they aren't expressions.

Comment: Thank god this is a duplicate, this question was answered by absolutely horrid discussions with terrible answers

Comment: Calling functions with the ternary operator is OK. Calling methods is definitely *not*, even if you find a way to make it work by converting the expressions to actions. The code becomes much harder to read and becomes opaque to analyzers and tools.

Answer (score 3):

The ternary operator should return a value. So if your functions will return the same kind of value then you can use the ternary operator for functions.

So if you remove the extra quotes and assuming that your two functions return the same kind of value as in the below case assuming them to return `Action`  then it is good.

```
Action a = (input < 0) ? RunScriptA() : RunScriptB();
```

or simply:

```
var a = (input < 0) ? RunScriptA() : RunScriptB();
```

Comment: What if the functions do not return a value as is evident from the OP?

Comment: If you don't show the assignement part ....

Comment: _"Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"_

Comment: `Action a = (...) RunScriptA()` only works if those methods return `Action`s.

Comment: "method returns `Action` s" means?

Comment: @dotNET what part of that sentence is hard to understand? `Action a = SomeMethod()` (note the parentheses) will only compile if `SomeMethod()` returns `Action`.

Comment: Why did you update this with the type Action? OP didnt mention the return type of ScriptA and ScriptB, just use var to avoid further complication, this thread is absolutely bulking with unuseful answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use a delegate for this kind of stuff. You can do something like this:

```
Action a = (input < 0) ? RunScriptA : RunScriptB; 
a();
```

Comment: Why use a delegate when one can simply make the call?

Comment: Having his desired function stored in variable has its uses, e.g. he could forward it to another function as param etc.

Comment: Not least of the benefits is that he learns the use of delegate.

Comment: I don't know about this, OP clearly want to actually run the code. This smeels like overcomplication. Just because he'll learn the use of delegates he should not make his code look ugly.

Comment: It also has its drawbacks. This line is harder to read *and* prevents analyzers and refactoring tools from understanding what is going on. A simple `if/else` is far better.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: He already has if-else in place. His question was that he wanted to minimize those 4 lines to possibly 2 or 1, that's what this answer is doing.

Comment: In this case, the proper answer is "Don't do it", not "This gimmick will do it". You can write the entire if/else in a single line if you want (it would still be ugly). Jon Skeet's answer in the duplicate question explains this eloquently.

Comment: A single line if has an advantage over this code because it *doesn't* create temporary delegate objects that would need to be garbage collected.